# Group ID for "All Company" Group in Yammer

Tags: yammer

I'm using the Yammer REST API to fetch data about messages posted in our Yammer network.
I can get messages from any group by passing the group ID.
But I don't know the group ID for the All Company group.

How can I find the group ID for the All Company group?

Answer (score 3):

Use `https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/messages/general.json`.

You can see the other built-in feed type endpoints such as `my_feed` and `private` here: http://developer.yammer.com/restapi/#rest-messages

Answer (score 3):

Yammer API POST call with parameter `group_id` allows posting message to a group, but not to AllCompany.

Same POST call with parameter `feed_id` allows posting message to a group and to AllCompany group (feed).

Use `feed_id` instead of `group_id` and `all` as id.

Answer (score 2):

first get all the groups 
using this API
https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/groups.json

in that group array check out the group full name. and you can use id of that array item. that will be your group id.

Comment: Although not directly relevant to the question, I found this helpful, thank you. This endpoint appears to be undocumented.

Answer (score 0):

Use https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/messages.json.

This will give All public messages in the user’s (whose access token is being used to make the API call henceforth referred to as current user) Yammer network. Corresponds to “All” conversations in the Yammer web interface.

also refer answer from by @mleroy in earlier message.

Answer (score 0):

use "**all**" as feed id for All company group.

I know this post is a bit old but it might help someone.
On every group page of Yammer, there is a section called Access Options on the right had side.
Click on the link "Embed this group in your side". It will give you JS code for the group which will include Feed ID as well.

Answer (score 0):

Using this api you can able access all messages

```
https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/messages.json
```

from the response json you can see the group id of all message groups.You can notice that 'group_created_id' is null for all company group.

I dont think that group id for all company is 'All',because that parameter is an integer,So just pass null.

Answer (score 0):

Its a bit weird, but I found out that the **group_created_id** field is **null** when the message belongs to  "All Company"

So you can use messages.json as mentioned before to get all public messages,
or if you want to search for messages by groups, you can get a list of groups ids and use :

```
https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/messages/in_group/{group-id}.json
```

and after that use messages.json, and go over the messages and search for those who has the field **group_created_id** set as **null**

Hope it will help someone someday :P

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requirement of embedding Yammer All company feed for which I needed the Feed ID and this worked for me-
 feedType: "general",
  feedId: "all"

Hope this helps!